# Calculating limit of a function without using L'Hospital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to calculate the following limit without using L'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{{\sinh(x) + x + x \ln(x)}}{{e^x}}$$

I am only allowed to use limit rules for sequences (e.g. squeeze theorem) and the series representation of ${e^x}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Use the definition of $\sinh$ and think about the limits of the four individual terms you get.